Public static class and methods not found in NuGet package
I'm running into an odd issue where I've developed a NuGet package. Because of the architecture of the legacy software I'm trying to write new functionality for, this is in .NET Framework 4.6.1 (I know, I know. We're working toward upgrading). The NuGet package is written in C#, while the app that will reference the NuGet package is in VB .NET that is in .NET Framework 4.6.1. The legacy app leverages three total NuGet packages I've written for this solution, but they are not appearing as errors.
The issue is in the title for this question. The public static class and methods in the NuGet package I've written are being marked as "not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level." Because of this error, I obviously cannot build.
I've tried the following:

Removing BIN/OBJ folders
Rebuilding/Cleaning and Building the solutions
Incrementing the NuGet version to verify old references are not held onto
Adding NuGet package references that support my NuGet package (Json supporting packages, mainly)
Removing and readding the NuGet package references to my packages

It may also be worth noting that the branch I'm on for the legacy application builds without changes, it also builds with my NuGet packages referenced. It doesn't build as soon as I added the calls into the NuGet package. I'm wondering if it's a an issue with the Wait() function, but I can't seem to derive the actual issue at hand. The errors that come up in the output during build just say the same 'not found/inaccessible' language.
Code samples below:
Within the NuGet package, I have the following code.
public static class ClassInNugetPackage
{
    public static async Task Initialize(string customerNumber, int locationId)
    {
        await SystemState.Instance.Initialize(customerNumber, locationId);
    }

    public static async Task SetApiUrl(string url)
    {
        await SystemState.Instance.SetApiUrl(url);
    }
}

The legacy application will call this in a form constructor like this:
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()

    Dim customerNumber = "170"
    Dim customerLocationId = 2140
    NamespaceInNugetPackage.ClassInNugetPackage.SetApiUrl("https://localhost:7012").Wait()
    NamespaceInNugetPackage.ClassInNugetPackage.Initialize(customerNumber, customerLocationId).Wait()

    If ClassInNugetPackage.BooleanValue.IsEnabled Then
        MsgBox("Yes!")
    End If
    
    ...
End Sub


Is the NuGet package public? If so, can you tell us which one it is, and what the actual class and method you're trying to use are?

If a method is declared as async you should Await it, even in VB. But I'm not sure that was an option yet back with 4.6.1 However, since you control the NuGet package and the legacy app uses these in a synchronous way, I'd change the package to add equivalent synchronous methods the legacy app can call. Within the package you can just call and await the async methods, so there's no actual code duplication.

@JonSkeet The NuGet package is a private solution within my place of business, so I can't share it publicly, unfortunately. The code I've included here is fairly 1:1 with the code I have in our code base. The namespaces and class names have been replaced is all. Do you think that I may be missing a package or reference that may resolve this?
@ JoelCoehoorn I'll give that a try and see if it resolves the issue.

Intellisense is showing that the namespaces and classes are visible, I'm able to autocomplete and see specific public methods I've exposed on the class name, however when building, Visual Studio fails it out. My next big steps are going to be trying an MSBuild outside of visual studio, and if that works, I'll see if I need to update or repair Visual Studio.

@JoelCoehoorn I'd generally agree, but Wait can be acceptable in some cases e.g. a console app.

It seems like something may be broken with your build process; I made a test solution with a Framework 4.6.1 C# library consisting of a public static class with a static awaitable function, and a Framework 4.6.1 VB console program that referenced the C# library and (as the only statement in the program) called Wait on the result of calling the routine.  It built without error.

If you're currently using PackageRef, what happens if you switch to using packages.config?

NuGet assumes packages are immutable, which means every time you modify a package (add new APIs, fix bugs, etc), you "need" to increment the package version. Alternatively, you can delete the package from your global packages directory, but if anyone else has restored an earlier iteration of the package version, NuGet isn't going to download the newer copy on their machine unless they also delete the package locally.

@zivkan see item 3 under "I've tried the following:".

You mention that you only got one "error", did you verify that there were no warnings about package resolution?  Sometimes there will be issues there that don't halt the build at that point but lead to errors later.  It may help to increase the verbosity of the output from the build to get more information on resolution of reference assemblies.

@Craig I appreciate your input here as well. I used the .NET upgrade tool to migrate to an SDK project temporarily to see if my output would be more reflective of the causal issue. When I attempted to build, there were detected package downgrades that I missed earlier on; So I reverted my changes through git, then downgraded my nuget package's references. When I went to build I ran into an unrelated issue, so I'm chasing that down now.
I'll update once I've resolved that issue. Thanks for your contributions, all, they've helped me get more direction here.

First off, I did not come to this resolution by myself. The comments of the community really steered me in a better direction, and led to this resolution. The codebase that I'm attempted to add functionality to is older and has a lot of references to older versions of NuGet packages (again, we're working on upgrading them).
I'm able to build now because I did the following:

Made sure I was on a branch of the core application git repository
Used the .NET Upgrade Assistant to move to the .NET SDK format
Attempted to build (this changed the output message that Visual Studio gave me, stating that it detected two package downgrades).
Reverted the legacy application via git
Rebuilt the legacy application to make sure I was in a successful build state.
Downgraded Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces and System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions to the versions found in the legacy application
Incremented my NuGet package assembly information
Ran NuGet pack in my nuget package directory via Windows Terminal
Referenced the new NuGet Package version in the legacy app
Built the legacy application successfully
Added my code
Built the legacy app with the code that references the NuGet packages successfully.

Thanks all for your help, and especially to Craig for giving the direction that led to the packageref and packages.config. This made me think of leveraging the Upgrade Assistant to see if the output would differ, and it did. Before the Upgrade Assistant migration to .NET SDK, I saw a singular error for each instance of calling my NuGet package, which was of the same verbiage (not found or not accessible), which is what confused me.
Thank you all for your consideration, input, and help. This got me to the next step!
